# Mysql query, selecting two values in one field

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

In the table above table 'sent' I use, among other things, two fields: 'opened' and emailnumber.

I'm looking for a mysql query that the people who opened email number 1 and/or email number 2 one or more times

So in the example it would be everyone, except Fred
I think it's simple, but I can't find the solution

Comment: `SELECT` _columns_ `FROM` table `WHERE` _conditions_.

Comment: And a condition can be like `columnname = value`. And you can use `AND` and `OR` if you have several conditions.

Comment: AND goes before OR. Sometimes you might need parentheses, like `(cond1 OR cond2) AND cond3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT name
FROM table
GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM(open > 0);
```

Comment: Are you sure the parenthesis after SUM are in the right place?

Comment: @mousetail 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks friends for your help, I understand the solution...